# Vanishing of Tor

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unit. Vanishing of $\operatorname{Tor}_0(M,N)$ ([see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93228/what-does-a-zero-tensor-product-imply)) for two finitely generated $R$ modules $M$ and $N$ implies $\operatorname{Ann}M+ \operatorname{Ann}N=R$. Can we get something similar for vanishing of $\operatorname{Tor}_i(M,N)$ for $i\geq 1$?

Comment: I suggest you clarify what you mean by `something similar'. For example, given any ideal $I$, $\mathrm{Tor}^1(R,R/I)=0$, but $\mathrm{Ann}\, R+\mathrm{Ann}\, R/I=I$.

Comment: @Mohan, I mean a ring theoretic condition like in the case of $Tor_0$ will be a good start.

Comment: I do not understand. In $\mathrm{Tor}^0$case there is no ring theoretic condition. So, what do you mean?

Comment: $Tor^{0}(M,N)$ vanishes implies $Ann M +Ann N=R$, which i call a ring theoretic condition.

Comment: If either $M$ or $N$ is flat (or, stronger condition, projective, or, even stronger condition, free, as in Mohan's example), then Tor$_i(M,N)=0$ for all $i\geq 1$.  This seems like bad news, because it says that if one of $M$ and $N$ is nice, the other can be whatever you like.  But on second thought, I guess that doesn't rule out the possibility of a nice answer.

Comment: @Hugh, you are right, i saw this and thought this is really bad news, but there can still be a "satisfying" answer.