# $A\otimes_{\mathbb C}B$ is finitely generated as a $\mathbb C$-algebra. Does this imply that $A$ and $B$ are finitely generated?

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products

Consider $A$ and $B$ two $\mathbb C$-algebras such that $A\otimes_{\mathbb C}B$ is finitely generated as a $\mathbb C$-algebra. Does this imply that $A$ and $B$ are finitely generated?

I know that for general algebras, this is false. Indeed $\mathbb Q$ is infinitely generated over $\mathbb Z$ but the tensor product $ \mathbb Q\otimes_\mathbb Z \mathbb Z_2 =0$. For $\mathbb C$-algebras however, I just can't seem to find a counter-example.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, it does, as long as $A$ and $B$ are both not the zero ring (obviously $A\otimes 0=0$ is finitely generated for any $A$).  Choose a finite set of generators of $A\otimes_\mathbb{C} B$; each of these is a finite sum of tensors $a\otimes b$.  Let $A_0\subseteq A$ be the subalgebra generated by all the $a$'s appearing in these tensors.  Then $A_0$ is finitely generated, and we see that the natural map $A_0\otimes_\mathbb{C} B\to A\otimes_\mathbb{C} B$ is surjective (since its image contains all of the tensors $a\otimes b$ in our generators).  This means $A/A_0\otimes_\mathbb{C} B=0$, so as long as $B\neq 0$, we must have $A/A_0=0$ and so $A_0=A$.  Thus $A$ is finitely generated.  By the same argument, $B$ is also finitely generated.

This argument clearly works with $\mathbb{C}$ replaced by any field.  Much more generally, a similar argument shows that if $R$ is any base ring and $A$ and $B$ are $R$-algebras such that $B$ is faithfully flat over $R$, then if $A\otimes_R B$ is finitely generated as a $B$-algebra (in particular, if it is finitely generated as an $R$-algebra), then $A$ is finitely generated as an $R$-algebra.

Comment: The fact that $B\neq 0$ implies $A_0 = A$ seems to be the crux of the argument, since that's where the proof would fail for $\mathbb{Q} \otimes _{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}_2$.  Although this seems obvious to me, I feel like I'm on slightly shaky ground.

Comment: We can choose a vector subspace $A_1\subseteq A$ such that $A=A_0\oplus A_1$ as vector spaces, and so $A_0\otimes B\to A\otimes B=A_0\otimes B\oplus A_1\otimes B$ is surjective iff $A_1\otimes B=0$.  If $B\neq 0$, this is true iff $A_1=0$, which means $A_0=A$.

Comment: yeah, that definitely takes care of the vector space case, which is the OP's question.

Comment: Why do we have if $B\neq 0$ ,  $A_1\otimes B=0$  iff $A_1=0$? I sense that this is where the field argument comes in but it is still not quite clear.

Comment: @user306194: If $S$ is a basis for $A_1$ and $T$ is a basis for $B$, then $S\times T$ is a basis for $A_1\otimes B$.  A cartesian product of sets can be empty only if one of the factors is empty.

Comment: Nice and elementary.  There is this more general result http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93228/what-does-a-zero-tensor-product-imply?rq=1

Comment: hmm why can we write $A=A_0\oplus A_1$ though? Subalgebras are not necessarily subvectorspaces.

Comment: Why not?  they are closed under multiplication and addition, right?

Comment: The very definition of subalgebra is "vector subspace which is also a subring".