# $(A/\mathfrak{a}) \otimes_A M \simeq M / \mathfrak{a}M$ by tensoring the canonical exact sequence.

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products, exact-sequence

Say we have a commutative ring $A$, an $A$-module $M$, and an ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ in $A$.

Then we have the short exact sequence:

$$
0 \to \mathfrak{a} \hookrightarrow A \twoheadrightarrow A/\mathfrak{a} \to 0
$$

After tensoring with $M$ we're left with the exact sequence:

$\mathfrak{a} \otimes_A M \rightarrow A \otimes_A M \twoheadrightarrow A/\mathfrak{a} \otimes_A M \to 0$.

We know that $A \otimes_A M \simeq M$ and so $A \otimes_A M /\ker \pi \simeq A/\mathfrak{a} \otimes_A M$.  Where $\pi$ is the surjection in the last sequence.

$\ker \pi = \{ \sum a_i \otimes m_i : \sum \pi(a_i) \otimes m_i = 0 \}$, so how do I conclude that $\ker \pi \simeq \mathfrak{a}M$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tensor product is right exact, so the kernel of $\pi$ is the image of $\mathfrak{a} \otimes_A M \rightarrow A \otimes_A M=M$ which is $\mathfrak{a}M$.

[Proving that the tensor product is right exact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81640/proving-that-the-tensor-product-is-right-exact)