# Please just explain how the sequence are exact?

Tags: commutative-algebra

$\text{Ramification Lemma}:$

Let $A$ be a ring, $\alpha$ an ideal of $A$, and $M$ an $A$-module. Then prove $M/ \alpha M \cong (A/\alpha) \otimes_A M $.

**Proof:** We have the exact sequence: $$0 \to \alpha \to A \to A/\alpha \to 0.$$ (Why ?)

Tensoring with $M$ gives another exact sequence: 
$$ 0 \to \alpha \otimes A \to A \otimes M \to A/ \alpha \otimes M \to 0.$$
i.e, $$0 \to \alpha \otimes A \to M \to A/ \alpha \otimes M \to 0,    $$ because $A \otimes M=M$.

The image of $\alpha \otimes_A M$ in $M$ are sums of elements of the form $a_i \cdot m_i$,

where $a_i \in \alpha$ and $m_i \in M$. This implies $M/ \alpha M \cong A / \alpha \otimes_A M$.

Please just explain how the sequence are exact?

what are the functions like $\alpha \to A$, $A \to A/\alpha$ etc?

Comment: The second sequence  is not exact in general.

Comment: Why can't you use $Im$ and $ker$?

Comment: @ArcticChar, I mean I can not but it is has to be used. Actually I can not find the required functions like $ \alpha \to A$ and then $A \to A/\alpha$. What are those?

Comment: Ok, the maps are the inclusion $\alpha \to A$ and the projection $A\to A/\alpha$, where $f\mapsto f+\alpha$.

Comment: @ArcticChar, Why $A \otimes M=M$ ? Is it by absorption property of tensor product?

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR Observe that the map $x\otimes m \to xm$ yields an isomorphism between $A \otimes M $ and $M$.

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2714188/a-mathfraka-otimes-a-m-simeq-m-mathfrakam-by-tensoring-the-canonic?rq=1