# Prove $(A/\mathfrak{a})\otimes_A F\simeq F/\mathfrak{a}F$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, tensor-products

> Let $A$ be a ring, $\mathfrak{a}$ a *right* ideal of $A$, $F$ a *left*
>   $A$-module and $\mathfrak{a}F$ the sub-$\mathbf{Z}$-module of $F$
>   generated by the elements of the  form $\lambda x$ where
>   $\lambda\in\mathfrak{a}$ and $x\in F$. Then there is a canonical
>   $\mathbf{Z}$-module isomorphism $$\pi:(A/\mathfrak{a})\otimes_A
>  F\rightarrow F/\mathfrak{a}F$$ such that for all $\bar{\lambda}\in
>  A/\mathfrak{a}$ and all $x\in F$, $\pi(\bar{\lambda}\otimes x)$ is the
>   class mod. $\mathfrak{a}F$ of $\lambda x$, where
>   $\lambda\in\bar{\lambda}$.

This result is supposed to be a corollary of the following fact:

> Given two exact sequence $E'\xrightarrow{u} E\xrightarrow{v}
>  E''\rightarrow0$ and $F'\xrightarrow{s} F\xrightarrow{t}
>  F''\rightarrow 0$ of right $A$-linear and left $A$-linear mappings,
>   respectively, the $\mathbf{Z}$-linear mapping $$v\otimes t:E\otimes_A
>  F\rightarrow E''\otimes F''$$ is surjective and its kernel is equal to
>   $\text{Im}(u\otimes 1_F)+\text{Im}(1_E\otimes s)$.

**Attempt:**

We can can consider the ring $A$ as a right $A$-module. Note that
$$\mathfrak{a}F=\left\{y\ |\ (\exists\alpha)(\alpha\in\mathbf{Z}^{(\mathfrak{a}\times F)}\ \land y=\sum_{(\lambda,y)\in\mathfrak{a}\times F}\alpha_{\lambda x}\lambda x)\right\}.$$
Let $i:\mathfrak{a}\rightarrow A$ and $j:\mathfrak{a}F\rightarrow F$ be the canonical injection. On the other hand, let $p:A\rightarrow A/\mathfrak{a}$ and $q:F\rightarrow F/\mathfrak{a}F$ be the canonical surjections. We have two exact sequence $\mathfrak{a}\xrightarrow{i}A\xrightarrow{p}A/\mathfrak{a}\rightarrow0$ and $\mathfrak{a}F\xrightarrow{j}F\xrightarrow{q}F/\mathfrak{a}F\rightarrow 0$. Hence 
$$p\otimes q:A\otimes_A F\rightarrow A/\mathfrak{a}\otimes_A F/\mathfrak{a}F$$
is a $\mathbf{Z}$-linear surjection with kernel $\text{Im}(i\otimes 1_F)+\text{Im}(1_A\otimes j)$.

But this is not close to what I am looking for. Should I be tensoring different linear maps? Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is essentially
[$(A/\mathfrak{a}) \otimes_A M \simeq M / \mathfrak{a}M$ by tensoring the canonical exact sequence.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2714188/a-mathfraka-otimes-a-m-simeq-m-mathfrakam-by-tensoring-the-canonic?rq=1)

For right $A$-modules write
$$\mathfrak a \xrightarrow{\iota} A \xrightarrow{\pi} A/\mathfrak a \to 0$$
and for left $A$-modules
$$0\to F \xrightarrow{1_F} F\to 0$$
Then your theorem gives a surjective map
$$\pi\otimes 1_F\colon A\otimes_A F\to (A/\mathfrak a)\otimes_A F$$
which kernel is $\mathrm{im}( \iota\otimes 1_F )$. (Why?)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If $h:F\rightarrow A\otimes_A F,\,y\mapsto1\otimes y$, is the canonical right $A$-module isomorphism, then $[\pi\otimes 1_F]\circ h:F\rightarrow(A/\mathfrak{a})\otimes_A F$ is the surjection I am looking for, right? I have to show that $\text{Ker}([\pi\otimes 1_F]\circ h)=\mathfrak{a}F$?

Comment: Also, is my definition of $\mathfrak{a}F$ correct?

Comment: Exactly! 
Your $\mathfrak a F$ also looks right, although I prefer to think about it in simpler terms – the set spanned by $af$ for $a\in \mathfrak a,~f\in F$.