# Tensor Product of Quotient.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, tensor-products, quotient-spaces

Let $K$ be a field and $L/K$ a field extension. Suppose $A$ is a $K$-algebra and $I$ is an ideal. I want to show that
$$ (A/I\otimes_K L) \to (A\otimes_K L)/(I\otimes_K L)$$

So i define a map
$$f: A\otimes_K L \to (A/I)\otimes_K L $$
by
$$ f(a\otimes \lambda)  =(a+I) \otimes \lambda$$
So I wish to show that the kernel of $f$ is $(I\otimes_K L)$. It is clear to me that $(I\otimes_K L) \subseteq  \operatorname{Ker}(f)$.

However, I'm having difficulties showing the reverse inclusion. If $\{b_i \}_i$ is a $K$-basis for $L$, then if $a\otimes \lambda \in  \operatorname{Ker}(f)$, then we write $\lambda = \sum_i \alpha_ib_i$ for $\alpha_i\in K$. Then
$$ 0=f(a\otimes \lambda) = \sum_i f(\alpha_ia\otimes b_i) = \sum_i (\alpha_ia+I)\otimes b_i.$$
Now, I want to conclude that since the sum is zero, we must have that each term is zero and hence $\alpha_i a+I=0$. But I'm not sure I can conclude this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know about flat modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a direct proof of the right exactness of the tensor product functor.
This is usually proved by applying left exactness of hom functor.
However, you can find a direct proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2330520/54738).

Your statement can proved very briefly by applying exactness properties of tensor functor as follows.
First note the exact sequence of $K$-modules
$$\{0\}\to I\to A\to A/I\to\{0\}$$
Since $L$ is a free, hence flat, $K$-module, 
tensoring with $L$ gives the exact sequence of $L$-modules
$$\{0\}\to I\otimes_KL\to A\otimes_KL\to(A/I)\otimes_KL\to\{0\}$$
from which we get an isomorphisms of $L$-module
$$(A/I)\otimes_KL\cong(A\otimes_KL)/(I\otimes_KL)$$

Comment: I like this proof but i'm looking to see why this isomorphism holds, so i'm want to get "my hands dirty" so to speak and complete the above proof.