# Is this tensor product of $ \mathbb Q(\sqrt { 2 }) $ a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am trying to prove that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}}\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is not a field, but I do not know which is the right isomorphism. I am thinking of 
$$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})[x]/(x^2-2)\cong\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}}\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}).$$ 
Could someone help, please? Thank you so much.

Comment: Over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, $x^2 - 2$ factors as $(x - \sqrt{2})(x + \sqrt{2})$. Then you can apply the Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: FYI: I happen to have written an answer on MathOverFlow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/280081/tensor-product-of-field-extensions/280090#280090 The example given there might be useful to you.

Answer (score 4):

The isomorphism you have listed is exactly right! One way of seeing this is by remembering for for two $K$-modules $A$ and $L$, we have

$$A/I \otimes_K L \cong (A \otimes_K L) / (I \otimes_K L)$$

(cf. [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3097853/tensor-product-of-quotient?rq=1))

So, for us, we rewrite
$$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) \otimes_\mathbb{Q} \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$$
as 
$$\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-2) \otimes_\mathbb{Q} \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}),$$ 
and then apply the above identity to get 
$$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})[x]/(x^2 - 2)$$
which is *not* a field, since $x^2-2$ is not $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$-irreducible.

---

I hope this helps ^_^