# Does $M/A \cong M/B$ imply $A = B$ for an $R$-module $M$ if $A \subseteq B$?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Let $R$ be a ring and $M$ an $R$-module.
Suppose I know that
$$
M/A \cong M / B
$$
as $R$-modules and $A,B$ are submodules of $M$ such that $A \subseteq B$.
Is it then the case that $A = B$?

I was trying to figure out details of the accepted solution of
[Proving that the tensor product is right exact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81640/proving-that-the-tensor-product-is-right-exact)

We have
$$A\otimes_R M\xrightarrow{\alpha\otimes Id}B\otimes_R M\xrightarrow{\beta\otimes Id}C\otimes_R M\rightarrow 0$$
and from the solution it follows that: let
$D$ be the image of $\alpha \otimes \operatorname{Id}$ then $(B \otimes M)/D \to C \otimes M$
is an isomorphism (assuming we have already shown $\beta \otimes \operatorname{Id}$ is surjective). It follows that
$(B \otimes M)/D \cong (B \otimes M)/\ker (\beta \otimes \operatorname{Id})$, but I was wondering how I can show that $D = \ker (\beta \otimes \operatorname{Id})$ in fact equal assuming $D \subseteq \ker (\beta \otimes \operatorname{Id})$.... thank you

Comment: The statement in the title is not true for infinite dimensional vector spaces. Pick $M$ any infinite dimensional vector space, $A=\{0\}$ and $B$ any nontrivial finite dimensional subspace of $M$. Then $A$ and $B$ are not even isomorphic.

Comment: Regarding the right exactness of the tensor product: the kernel of the map $(B\otimes M)/D \to C\otimes M$ is $\ker(\beta\otimes \operatorname{Id})/D$. So if the map is an isomorphism (in particular injective), then $\ker(\beta\otimes \operatorname{Id})/D = 0$. But this means $\ker(\beta\otimes\operatorname{Id}) = D$.

Comment: @Claudius It makes sense now, thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is "no". Take the free module $M$ freely generated by $x_i$ for positive integers $i$ and its factor-module $M'$  freely generated by $x_{2n}$,. the homomorphism consists of killing all $x$'s with odd indices. Then $M, M'$ are isomorphic.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes if what you are assuming is an isomoprhism is the canonical map $M/A\longrightarrow M/B$ induced by the inclusion $A\subseteq B$: the kernel of this map if $B/A$, which is zero if and only if $A=B$. This is the situation in your question.