# If $f \colon M \to N$ is surjective, $K \subseteq \ker f \subseteq M$, and $M/K \cong N$, does that imply $K = \ker f$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $M, N$ be $R$-(bi)modules, $f \colon M \to N$ a surjection, and $K \subseteq \ker f \subseteq M$ as submodules. I want to show that if $M/K \cong N$, that implies $K = \ker f$.

It seems intuitively true that $\ker f$ should be the only submodule $K$ of $M$ such that $M/K \cong N$, but I'm having a hard time showing it (or finding a counterexample). The main difficulty is that the isomorphism $M/K \cong N$ is not assumed to come from $f$.

Comment: My intuition is that there is no reason for this to be true.  Anxious to see the answers that follow.  (Lots of copies of $\mathbb{Z}$, probably.)

Comment: Indeed! Looks like the similar question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3816603/343314 has similar counterexamples, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this does not hold. Let $R = \mathbb{Z}$.

Consider $M = \bigoplus\limits_{i = 0}^\infty \mathbb{Z}$, generated by $\{z_i\}_{i = 0}^\infty$.

Consider $N = M$.

Consider the map $f : M \to N$ defined by $f(z_0) = 0$ and $f(z_{i + 1}) = z_i$.

Then $f$ is surjective, and its kernel is the copy of $\mathbb{Z}$ generated by $z_0$.

However, let $K = 0$. Then $M / K \cong M \cong N$.

Note that there's nothing special about $\mathbb{Z}$ here - we could have substituted any nonzero ring and gotten this result.

Comment: @MichaelMorrow Good point, fixed it.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you!