# Tensor any abelian group to a short exact sequence of abelian groups

Tags: homological-algebra, tensor-products, exact-sequence

Given a short exact sequence of abelian groups,
\begin{eqnarray}
0\rightarrow A\xrightarrow{h}B\xrightarrow{k}C\rightarrow0,
\end{eqnarray}
we tensor it with an arbitrary abelian group $G$. How to prove (in an elementary way starting from definitions) the following sequence is exact:
\begin{eqnarray}
A\otimes G\xrightarrow{h\otimes 1}B\otimes G\xrightarrow{k\otimes 1}C\otimes G\rightarrow0,
\end{eqnarray}
where the leftmost zero inclusion has been discarded.

Comment: See Prop. 2.18 in Atiyah-Macdonald for example. This can help too: [Proving that the tensor product is right exact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81640/proving-that-the-tensor-product-is-right-exact)

Comment: @Michael Many thanks and that's really helpful!

Comment: No problem. Those resources prove it for $R$-modules where $R$ is a ring, but the case for abelian groups is more simple: just forget the $R$-multiplication.