# A question about tensor products and equality of expressions

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Let $R$ be a (unital) ring and let $A$ be a right $R$-module and let $B$ be a left $R$-module.
Then we can define the tensor product $A\otimes_{R} B$, with the expected relations. In particular, we have that

$$a\cdot r\otimes b=a\otimes r\cdot b$$

for all $a\in A$, $r\in R$ and $b\in B$, where $\cdot$ is used to denote the appropriate module action.

Inspired by the question
[https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81640/proving-that-the-tensor-product-is-right-exact], I started wondering about when the equality
$$a\otimes b=\tilde{a}\otimes\tilde{b}$$
holds in general. In essence, this seems to come down to the question of what can be said in general about $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ if
$$a\otimes b=0.$$
Clearly, if either $a=0$ or $b=0$, then the statement is trivially true, so let us assume that both $a$ and $b$ are nonzero. Then what are necessary and sufficient conditions for the tensor product $a\otimes b$ to be zero? Right now I'm thinking that it should be necessary for at least one of $a$ and $b$ to be a zero divisor (i.e., there is an $r\neq 0$ such that $a\cdot r=0$ or $r\cdot b=0$).

Assuming that $a$ is a zero divisor, then my logic goes as follows: the expression $a\otimes b=0$ iff $b=r\cdot c$ for a $c\in B$ and $r\in R$ such that $a\cdot r=0$.

Likewise, if we assume that $b$ is a zero divisor then my logic is that $a\otimes b=0$ iff $a=c\cdot r$ for a $c\in A$ and $r\in R$ such that $r\cdot b=0$.

What I'm interested in knowing is whether my conclusion is correct or if I'm mistaken and there is a counterexample that breaks my argument. If so, what are the real necessary and sufficient conditions for an expression $a\otimes b$ to be zero? And more broadly, what can be said about $a,\tilde{a},b$ and $\tilde{b}$ if $a\otimes b=\tilde{a}\otimes\tilde{b}$? Because right now I'm thinking that this is true iff there is an $r\in R$ such that either $a=\tilde{a}\cdot r$ and $\tilde{b}=r\cdot b$ or $b=r\cdot\tilde{b}$ and $\tilde{a}=a\cdot r$.

Comment: Sorry, what is $\tilde a$?

Comment: This is just some other element in $A$. Likewise, $\tilde{b}\in B$ is just some element. I just didn't bother with writing it out explicitly in the original post.

Comment: The annoying answer is: "whether or not $a\otimes b$ can be linked to $\tilde a\otimes\tilde b$ in finitely many applications of the tensor relations"